# why i can not do sql injection testing using mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

i was trying to check a web site for an sql injection attack and amazed to see it not very very simple to prevent because below is the simple code .

```
$sql="select * from user_acount where login_id='".$username."' and password='".$password."' and status='1' ";
```

i can not do any sql injection to test it. i wrote the following

1st Attempt to check sql injection

```
Login:  admin'--
Password:'i typed nothing here '
```

Result Wrong password you cannot login.

2nd:

```
Login:  admin or 1=1 --' 
Password:''
```

Result Wrong password you cannot login.

3rd:

```
Login:  admin' or 1=1 
Password:''
```

4th:
    Login:  admin or 1=1'-- 
    Password:''

Result Wrong password you cannot login.

Can anyone please explain what is stopping me ? i am not using prepared statements nor i am using any filter class neither i have real_escape_string ?

Comment: I can't imagine how many websites magic quote have saved the life

Comment: Do you compare posted password with password from DB in PHP? I.e., do you have something like `if ( $password != $row['password'] ) { showError('Wrong password you cannot login'); }`?

Comment: so this is 100% sql injection safe code because magic_qoute is enabled cool and easy method to protect sql injection. ins't

Comment: No, it is not cool. Not 100% portable, deprecated, soon to be gone, unsafe in some cases. Prepared statements - that is cool and easy-to-use protection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two possibilities:

1. There is no `login_id` with `admin`, therefore the query looks like:

   ```
   select * from user_acount where login_id='admin'
   ```
2. [`magic_quotes`](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) have been enabled, resulting in queries like:

   ```
   select * from user_acount where login_id='admin\'--' and password='' and status='1'
   select * from user_acount where login_id='admin or 1=1 --\'' and password='' and status='1'
   ```

   The last query will always fail, even if magic quotes was turned off:

   ```
   select * from user_acount where login_id='admin or 1=1 --'' and password='' and status='1'
   ```

   Because `--` comments within strings do not work, the query is interpreted like:

   ```
   select * from user_acount where login_id='STRING'' and password='' and status='1'
   ```

   As you can see, this will result in a syntax error after `'STRING'`

Comment: thanks this is great so does it mean 100% sql injection safe?

Comment: As long as there are no special character sets are involved, yes. **But do not rely on it**, it's deprecated in PHP 5.3 and might be removed in the future. You'd better use prepared statement or escape data using functions like `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Answer (score 5):

- [Magic Quotes](http://php.net/manual/de/security.magicquotes.php) might be turned on (so user input is automatically processed to be better suited for composing database queries).
- [Register Globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) might be turned off (so you would have to use `$_REQUEST['username']` or related instead of `$username`).
- There might be a bug in your programm, that prevents the input `admin'--` from being stored in `$username` (e. g. form element names do not match variable names).

Answer (score 1):

You are entering a password which includes quotes. This breaks your SQL query, and presumably the code does not distinguish between an error and a legitimate "no such user" result, so you get the wrong password message.

Try leaving the password blank.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually call the `real_escape_string()` method, but I think `magic_quotes_gpc` is set to true.

> When magic_quotes are on, all '
>   (single-quote), " (double quote), \
>   (backslash) and NUL's are escaped with
>   a backslash automatically.

[Runtime Configuration - magic_quotes_gpc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with:

```
Login:  admin' or '1=1  
Password: admin' or '1=1
```

Also check for magic quotes turned on